# how to read Hbase current and previous versions of data from hive or impala?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, impala

I want to read Hbase current and previous versions of data from either hive or Impala.In my initial research, I found out that only current version can be accessed from Hive. So, currently is there any way to retrieve the older versions from either hive or Impala?

Comment: seems like its not possible for both hive and impala to see previous versions of cell data. pls. see my answer.

Comment: was my answer useful? did you find anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

**In case of Hive :** 
Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371987/accessing-hbase-table-data-from-hive-based-on-time-stamp)

Seems like it's not possible to get different versions of same cell in Hive(even though Hbase has multiple versions of the same cell ) which always return the cell with latest timestamp. I believe we can handle this in tactical way. we can append the previous version to Hbase row key or else as separate cell (name, value)
**In case of Impala :** 
Please see [limitations](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-0-x/topics/impala_hbase.html) section